# Confusion about the proof that optimizing InfoNCE equals to maximizing mutual information

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

In the appendix of [Representation Learning with Contrastive Predictive Coding](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03748), van den Oord et al. prove that optimizing InfoNCE is equivalent to maximize the mutual information between input image $x_t$ and the context latent $c_t$ as follows:
[image]

where $x_{t+k}$ is the image at time step $t+k$, $X_{neg}$ is a set of negative samples that do not appear in the sequence $x_t$ belongs to, and $N-1$ is the negative samples used to compute InfoNCE.

I'm confused about Equation $(8)$. van den Oord et al. stressed that Equation $(8)$ becomes more accurate as $N$ increases, but I cannot see why. Here's my understanding, for $x_j\in X_{neg}$, we have $p(x_j|c_t)\le p(x_j)$ . Therefore, $\sum_{x_j\in X_{neg}}{p(x_j|c_t)\over p(x_j)}\le N-1$ and this does not become accurate as $N$ increases. In fact, I think the gap between the left and right of $\le$ increases as $N$ increases. Do I make any mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Well, conditional probability (density) does not necessarily need to be no greater than its marginal probability (density). That means $p(x_j|c_t)\le p(x_j)$ is not always true. For example, consider two discrete r.v.s $X,Y\in\{0,1\}$ such that $$
P(X=0,Y=0)=0.05,\\
P(X=1,Y=0)=0.05,\\
P(X=0,Y=1)=0.05,\\
P(X=1,Y=1)=0.85
$$. We have $P(X=0)=0.1$; however, $P(X=0|Y=0)=0.5$.